# How to log thread name in libComponentLogger

Tags: ios, objective-c, libcomponentlogging

While using libComponentLogging, is there a way to show the thread the lcl_log() is called on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the back-ends already include the thread-id in their log messages, e.g. LogFile and SystemLog do this.

If you want to also include the NSThread's name, you can add that to the back-ends which you are using, e.g. for NSLog, you can add it like this:

```
 --- a/LCLNSLog.h
 +++ b/LCLNSLog.h
 @@ -84,8 +84,9 @@
 // A very simple logger, which redirects to NSLog().
 #define _lcl_logger(_component, _level, _format, ...) {                        \
     _lcl_logger_autoreleasepool_begin                                          \
-    NSLog(@"%s %s:%@:%d:%s " _format,                                          \
+    NSLog(@"%s [%@] %s:%@:%d:%s " _format,                                     \
           _lcl_level_header_1[_level],                                         \
+          [[NSThread currentThread] name],                                     \
           _lcl_component_header[_component],                                   \
           [@__FILE__ lastPathComponent],                                       \
           __LINE__,                                                            \
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, this will do the job (or something similar):

```
[NSThread currentThread].name
```

Comment: I want the library to show it... I don't want to type that in 500 log statements....